# Unable to get all the values from the list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have two list boxes named **categories** and **selected categories**. I have added a drag and drop function with **jQuery** where I can drag from the categories and drop into the selected categories list box. Even though the functionality works fine, I am facing an issue after dropping the items into the **selected category list box**. As my requirement is to get all the items in the **selected category list box** to an array, the list box item count `returns 0`. Below given are the code segments which I tried (I have tried using`for` loop and `foreach` loop).

Foreach loop ex:

```
    foreach (DataRowView drv in lbChosen.Items)
        {
            string categoryName = drv.ToString();
        }
```

For loop ex:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lbChosen.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string categoryName = lbChosen.Items[i].ToString();
        }
```

given below is the code segment which is used to implement the drag and drop functionality. ([Taken from this link](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-drag-and-drop-items-from-to-aspxlistbox-using-jquery-ui-e3417))

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v18.1, Version=18.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>How to drag and drop items from/to ASPxListBox using jQuery UI</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitalizejQuery() {
        $('.lbItem').draggable(
            {
                helper: 'clone'
            }
        );

        $('.listBoxLeft, .listBoxRight').droppable(
            {
                activeClass: "hover",
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    /* do nothing when the parent == destination */
                    if ($(ui.draggable).parents(".listBoxLeft").length != 0 && ($(this)).hasClass("listBoxLeft") ||
                        $(ui.draggable).parents(".listBoxRight").length != 0 && ($(this)).hasClass("listBoxRight"))
                        return;

                    var itemIndex = $(ui.draggable).parent().index(); // this is a fragile part of the application

                    var fromListBox, toListBox;

                    if ($(this).hasClass("listBoxRight")) { // determine a source and a destination
                        toListBox = lbChosen;
                        fromListBox = lbAvailable;
                    }
                    else {
                        toListBox = lbAvailable;
                        fromListBox = lbChosen;
                    }

                    toListBox.AddItem(fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).text,
                                      fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).value);

                    fromListBox.RemoveItem(itemIndex);

                    InitalizejQuery(); // repeat the initialization for new items
                }
            }
          );
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .lbItem
    {
        width: 200px;
    }

    /* like SelectedItem style */
    .ui-draggable-dragging
    {
        background-color: #A0A0A0;
        color: White;
    }

    /* small glowing effect */
    .hover
    {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <dx:ASPxGlobalEvents ID="ge" runat="server">
        <ClientSideEvents ControlsInitialized="function (s, e) { InitalizejQuery(); }" />
    </dx:ASPxGlobalEvents>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 35%">
                <dx:ASPxListBox ID="lbAvailable" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="lbAvailable"
                    Width="200px" Height="240px" CssClass="listBoxLeft">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="lbItem" />
                    <Items>
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxEditors Library" Value="ASPxEditors" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxGauges Suite" Value="ASPxGauges" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxGridView and Editors Suite" Value="ASPxGridView and Editors" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxHTMLEditor Suite" Value="ASPxHTMLEditor" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxperience Suite" Value="ASPxperience" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxPivotGrid Suite" Value="ASPxPivotGrid" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxScheduler Suite" Value="ASPxScheduler" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxSpellChecker" Value="ASPxSpellChecker" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="ASPxTreeList Suite" Value="ASPxTreeList" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="XtraReports Suite" Value="XtraReports" />
                        <dx:ListEditItem Text="XtraCharts Suite" Value="XtraCharts" />
                    </Items>
                </dx:ASPxListBox>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 30%">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 35%">
                <dx:ASPxListBox ID="lbChosen" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="lbChosen" Width="200px"
                    Height="240px" CssClass="listBoxRight">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="lbItem" />
                </dx:ASPxListBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

I need to know why I am unable to print the items to an array? where am i going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function InitalizejQuery() {
        $('.lbItem').draggable(
            {
                helper: 'clone'
            }
        );

        $('.listBoxLeft, .listBoxRight').droppable(
            {
                activeClass: "hover",
                drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    /* do nothing when the parent == destination */
                    if ($(ui.draggable).parents(".listBoxLeft").length != 0 && ($(this)).hasClass("listBoxLeft") ||
                        $(ui.draggable).parents(".listBoxRight").length != 0 && ($(this)).hasClass("listBoxRight"))
                        return;

                    var itemIndex = $(ui.draggable).parent().index(); // this is a fragile part of the application

                    var fromListBox, toListBox;

                    if ($(this).hasClass("listBoxRight")) { // determine a source and a destination
                        toListBox = lbChosen;
                        fromListBox = lbAvailable;
                    }
                    else {
                        toListBox = lbAvailable;
                        fromListBox = lbChosen;
                    }

                    //toListBox.AddItem(fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).text,
                    //                  fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).value);
                    $("#lbChosen").append(toListBox.AddItem(fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).text,
                                      fromListBox.GetItem(itemIndex).value));
                    fromListBox.RemoveItem(itemIndex);

                    //Robson Sousa's code
                    var category;
                    $('#lbChosen_LBT td').each(function () {
                        category = $(this).text();

                    });
                    console.log(category); //tried printing it on console. 

                    InitalizejQuery(); // repeat the initialization for new items
                }
            }
          );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of selected categories by JQuery, like this:

```
var categories = [];
var i =0;
$('#lbChosen_LBT td').each(function () {
   categories[i++] = $(this).text();
});
console.log(categories); //tried printing it on console
```

Comment: I has tested it on your page, in chrome console and it's working. Show me how you are using this code.

Comment: I have edited my question for your reference. I am getting undefined in the console while testing it.

Comment: I download your code and I have tested it. It's correct. But to improving it, this is better:

`var categories = [];
var i =0;
$('#lbChosen_LBT td').each(function () {
categories[i++] = $(this).text();
});
console.log(categories); //tried printing it on console.`

Put this code at the same place.
To test it, drag and drop same categories while look to your console.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try and get back to you. :) Please Update the answer if you are making any changes for your previous answers or adding anything extra.